# How to inject different ObjectMappers having different configurations through Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to have 2 different Jackson `ObjectMapper`s so that I that I can switch between using either one of them in my code. The 2 `ObjectMapper`s are going to have some slight differences in their configuration.

In my configuration file, I have them as 2 separate means this way:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    private ObjectMapper createMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        // And a few more other common configurations
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("standardObjectMapper")
    public ObjectMapper standardObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Product.class, new StandardProductSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("specialObjectMapper")
    public ObjectMapper specialObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        // In this mapper, I have a different serializer for the Product class
        module.addSerializer(Product.class, new SpecialProductSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

My plan is to inject and use one of those mappers whenever I need them. So in my test, I have something like this:

```
class SerializationTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("standardObjectMapper")
    private ObjectMapper standardObjectMapper;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("specialObjectMapper")
    private ObjectMapper specialObjectMapper;

    @Test
    void testSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
       Product myProduct = new Product("Test Product");

      String stdJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myProduct);
      String specialJson = specialObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(myProduct);

      // Both stdJson and specialJson are of the same value even though they should be different because the mappers have different serializers!
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the 2 `ObjectMapper`s, `standardObjectMapper` and `specialObjectMapper` both are using the same `StandardProductSerializer`.

I'm expecting the `specialObjectMapper` to use the `SpecialProductSerializer` but this isn't the case.

Shouldn't the 2 ObjectMappers be different? I assume the injection would be based on their individual names since their types are the same?

What should I do to fix the issue so that the 2 ObjectMappers can be using different Serializers?

---

**Update:**

I've tried using `Qualifiers` but I'm getting an error that the beans cannot be found:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.site.SerializationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'standardObjectMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="standardObjectMapper")}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Qualifiers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) to distinguish the beans? As an aside: I would suggest using constructor- or setter-injection. You can use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` to easily inject fields, but this will increase the exeuction time of your tests.

Comment: @Turing85 I've tried using Qualifiers but I'm getting the following error: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'standardObjectMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="standardObjectMapper")}`

Comment: Have you annotated both the injection point **and** the bean-method with the `@Qualifier(...)`?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I've updated my question with the use of Qualifers. I've put in both places and their names are the same.

Comment: Can you confirm that the beans are created, i.e. that the two methods are executed during startup?

Comment: @Turing85 I've just tried to put some print statements in the 2 methods and it seems like the print statements weren't printing anything to the console. So I suppose the beans aren't being created. Strangely, if I remove the Qualifiers, they work fine except that the Autowiring will pull only the `standardObjectMapper` but not the `specialObjectMapper`. I've actually created a helper method called `createMapper` but this isn't annotated as a bean though I'm using it in the 2 beans. Will this be of an issue in this case?

Comment: @Turing85 Also, other than adding print statements in the methods, what would be a better way to see whether the beans have been created? I just noticed that, for some reason, even when the bean has created, I may not necessarily see the output in the console.

Comment: Set breakpoints, start up the application in debug mode. Keep in mind that Spring provides a standard-`ObjectMapper`-bean, thus injection works without the providied beans being loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@Qualifier` should resolve your problem

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("standardMapper")
public ObjectMapper standardObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Product.class, new StandardProductSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("specialMapper")
public ObjectMapper specialObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    // In this mapper, I have a different serializer for the Product class
    module.addSerializer(Product.class, new SpecialProductSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    return mapper;
}
```

Then add `@Qualifier` with your `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("standardMapper")
private ObjectMapper standardObjectMapper;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("specialMapper")
private ObjectMapper specialObjectMapper;
```

Comment: I've tried this and it's giving me this error: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'standardObjectMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="standardObjectMapper")}`

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with the use of Qualifers. I've put in both places and their names are the same.

Comment: @Carven perhaps you configuration class is not scanned by spring and the beans are not created, put your class in the configuration folder in the same level with your bootstrap class(@SpringBootApplication)

Comment: I think the reason could be that I'm running the test in a unit test file. Since unit test files are by default resided in a different package, the component scan might not be able to find the bean.

Comment: If you create a test class, annotate it with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and 
@SpringBootTest should resolve the problem

Comment: Thanks! I just tried using that 2 annotations. That kind of resolved the issue with not getting the beans but there is a different error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.site.SerializationTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper)]`

Comment: If you use SpringBootTest add the bootstrap class, means the class annotated with SpringBootApplication like this: SpringBootTest(classes = {YourBootStrapClass.class})

Comment: Strange, I just tried adding my bootstrap class to the SpringBootTest annotation but I’m still getting that same error complaining that there are multiple declarations found.

Comment: You have to update your post with your configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Qualifier("specialObjectMapper") 
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper specialObjectMapper;

@Qualifier("standardMapper")
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper standardObjectMapper;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Qualifier` annotation in order to distinguish the different istances of ObjectMapper. (see: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

```
@Qualifier("objectMapper1") 
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objMapper1;
```

Answer (score 1):

could you please try this, it will inject bean based on name

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("standardObjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper standardObjectMapper;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("specialObjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper specialObjectMapper;
```

hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `@Configuration`-class is not scanned during DI startup. Normally, spring looks for configuration from the package the Application class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) resides.

I would suggest moving the `@Configuration` class in a sub-package of that in which the `@SpringBootApplication` resides.

There are other ways (e.g. [this one described at baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)) to change the root-package for component scanning. I would, however, not recommend doing this unless all other options have been exhausted.

Comment: Since the file I'm currently running it in a test file, the test file is resided in a different package from the configuration file. I have tried setting breakpoints when I'm running the main application and the beans do get created. But when I'm running the test file, the breakpoints in the 2 beans aren't hit.

Comment: There are other ways (e.g. [this one described at baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)) To get your test to work. I would, however, not recommend using this approach.